# Proper way of creating date fields in jsGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

So I'm a beginner using jsGrid to make a calendar grid, which looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU4V9.png

I've created the header fields as such:

```
var headerFields = [{ 
    name: "name",
    title: "", type: "text", 
    width: 60 
}];

for(var i = 1; i <= 31; i++){
    headerFields[i] = { 
        name: String(i), 
        title: String(i), 
        type: "text", 
        width: 20, 
        sorting: false, 
        inserting: false
     };
}

headerFields.push({ type: "control", width: 24, editButton: false });
```

And then that's initialized in the jsGrid itself as such:

```
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
    ...
    fields: headerFields,
    ...
 }
```

Aside from all months having 31 days I feel like this is a very non-kosher way of doing this, because if I want to reference a cell by a certain day it's done like "item[17]" which is so ambiguous, it feels like it should have another layer like "item.day(17)" but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to apply that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure, the problem is clear. Where and why do you want to access an item like `item.day(17)`?

Comment: For example the rowClick function passes an object array which includes the "item" object which contains all the fields as name:title. Which is basically just 'name:ada,1:"",2:"",3:""..etc', and those get sent as a server request variable on updating and inserting. I realize I can rename the days to something like "day1, day2", and access them by selectedRow.item.day2, but that still feels incomplete somehow.. I was hoping I could get the days into their own array in the item object, I figured that would be the "right" way to do it heh

Comment: Oh sorry man, didn't realize you were THE tabalin, but yeah I sometimes have to loop through the date columns per row and it seems clunky that I'm setting an offset based on where it begins and ends in the grid and then just looping through the cellIndexes. But I'm fairly new and I'm probably overcomplicating things, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 4):

working example of jsgrid date field

```
var db = {

    loadData: function(filter) {
        return $.grep(this.users, function(user) {
            return (!filter.Name || user.Name.indexOf(filter.Name) > -1);
        });
    },

    insertItem: function(item) {
        this.users.push(item);
    },

    deleteItem: function(item) {
        var index = $.inArray(item, this.users);
        this.users.splice(index, 1);
    }

};

window.db = db;

db.users = [
    {
        "Account": "D89FF524-1233-0CE7-C9E1-56EFF017A321",
        "Name": "Prescott Griffin",
        "RegisterDate": "2011-02-22T05:59:55-08:00"
    },
    {
        "Account": "06FAAD9A-5114-08F6-D60C-961B2528B4F0",
        "Name": "Amir Saunders",
        "RegisterDate": "2014-08-13T09:17:49-07:00"
    },
    {
        "Account": "EED7653D-7DD9-A722-64A8-36A55ECDBE77",
        "Name": "Derek Thornton",
        "RegisterDate": "2012-02-27T01:31:07-08:00"
    },
    {
        "Account": "2A2E6D40-FEBD-C643-A751-9AB4CAF1E2F6",
        "Name": "Fletcher Romero",
        "RegisterDate": "2010-06-25T15:49:54-07:00"
    },
    {
        "Account": "3978F8FA-DFF0-DA0E-0A5D-EB9D281A3286",
        "Name": "Thaddeus Stein",
        "RegisterDate": "2013-11-10T07:29:41-08:00"
    }
];

var MyDateField = function (config) {
    jsGrid.Field.call(this, config);
};

MyDateField.prototype = new jsGrid.Field({

    sorter: function (date1, date2) {
        return new Date(date1) - new Date(date2);
    },

    itemTemplate: function (value) {
        return new Date(value).toDateString();
    },

    insertTemplate: function (value) {
        return this._insertPicker = $("<input class='date-picker'>").datetimepicker();
    },

    editTemplate: function (value) {
        return this._editPicker = $("<input class='date-picker'>").datetimepicker();
    },

    insertValue: function () {
        return this._insertPicker.data("DateTimePicker").useCurrent();
    },

    editValue: function () {
        return this._editPicker.data("DateTimePicker").useCurrent();
    }
});

jsGrid.fields.date = MyDateField;

$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
    height: "90%",
    width: "100%",

    inserting: true,
    filtering: true,
    editing: true,
    paging: true,

    autoload: true,

    controller: db,

    fields: [
        { name: "Account", width: 150, align: "center" },
        { name: "Name", type: "text" },
        { name: "RegisterDate", type: "date", width: 100, align: "center" },
        { type: "control", editButton: false }
    ]
});
```

Refference: http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/L6wbmvfo/

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Moment, this worked for me:

```
        var DateField = function (config) {
            jsGrid.Field.call(this, config);
        };

        DateField.prototype = new jsGrid.Field({
            sorter: function (date1, date2) {
                return moment(date1) - moment(date2);
            },
            itemTemplate: function (value) {
                return moment(value).locale('en').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            },
        });

        jsGrid.fields.date = DateField;
```

I just ignored edit & insert functions because I don't need them.